# Как установить компилятор gcc с внешнего носителя?

Tags: gcc

На работе нет интернета, на компьютере установлена операционная система Ubuntu. Требуется установить компилятор gcc с помощью внешнего носителя. Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал разные способы.
Способ 1:

1. sudo apt-get download gcc на компьютере с интернетом
2. Скачать на флеш-накопитель
3. sudo dpkg gcc.deb на компьютере без интернета

Для осуществления действия 3 потребовалось по аналогичному алгоритму скачать около 30 различных библиотек и утилит. Я это сделал и на запрос gcc --version система отвечает, что версия 11 установлена. Но с-файлы компилятор не компилирует. Видимо

Способ 2 описан здесь https://losst.pro/kak-ustanovit-tar-gz-v-ubuntu?unapproved=137995&moderation-hash=05ab01c82c51e2095a835d58f4b45f93#comment-137995
Но он требует подключения к интернету для осуществления команды  sudo apt install checkinstall build-essential autoconf automake. Если пытаться установить все эти 4 утилиты через tar.gz, возникают ошибки, связанные с тем что некоторые файлы в этих архивах находятся не на своих местах.

Comment: Что означает "компилятор не компилирует"? Что происходит вместо компиляции?

Comment: Выдает "Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory"

Comment: Мой dpkg говорит, что это из пакета `cpp-11`, с ним всё нормально?

Comment: А вообще для такого дела вроде как есть [apt-offline](https://docs.xubuntu.org/1704/user/ru/offline-packages.html)

Comment: За apt-offline спасибо, буду пробовать.